# hash value for a line object

Tags: java, algorithm, hashcode

Here is a reference implementation of Line object, my confusion is from line 40 to line 43, the question is, if two lines are different, but the OR results of slope/intercept happens to be the same, will it have any issues (e.g. treat different lines the same because of the same hash values)? Since I think same hash value means the same Line.

If the current implementation for hash value do have the issue I mentioned, appreciate if anyone could help to provide some insights what are good implementation for hash value in my case.

```
1 public static Line findBestLine(GraphPoint[] points) {
2 Line bestLine = null;
3 HashMap<Line, Integer> line_count = new HashMap<Line, Integer>();
4 for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
5 for (int j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++) {
6 Line line = new Line(points[i], points[j]);
7 if (!line_count.containsKey(line)) {
8 line_count.put(line, 0);
9 }
10 line_count.put(line, line_count.get(line) + 1);
11 if (bestLine == null ||
12 line_count.get(line) > line_count.get(bestLine)) {
13 bestLine = line;
14 }
15 }
16 }
17 return bestLine;
18 }
19
20 public class Line {
21 private static double epsilon = .0001;
22 public double slope;
23 public double intercept;
24 private boolean infinite_slope = false;
25 public Line(GraphPoint p, GraphPoint q) {
26 if (Math.abs(p.x - q.x) > epsilon) { // if x’s are different
27 slope = (p.y - q.y) / (p.x - q.x); // compute slope
28 intercept = p.y - slope * p.x; // y intercept from y=mx+b
29 } else {
30 infinite_slope = true;
31 intercept = p.x; // x-intercept, since slope is infinite
32 }
33 }
34
35 public boolean isEqual(double a, double b) {
36 return (Math.abs(a - b) < epsilon);
37 }
38
39 @Override
40 public int hashCode() {
41 int sl = (int)(slope * 1000);
42 int in = (int)(intercept * 1000);
43 return sl | in;
44 }
45
46 @Override
47 public boolean equals(Object o) {
48 Line l = (Line) o;
49 if (isEqual(l.slope, slope) && isEqual(l.intercept, intercept)
50 && (infinite_slope == l.infinite_slope)) {
51 return true;
52 }
53 return false;
54 }
55 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since I think same hash value means the same Line.

No, it doesn't. This is a common misconception. If two objects have the same hash code, they *may* be equal - but they don't have to be. You should *never* treat equal hash codes as proof that two objects are equal.

The hash code used here is definitely poor in various ways, but it is at least valid.

As an extreme example, it's always *valid* (but almost always unhelpful) to write:

```
public override int hashCode() {
    return 5;
}
```

That guarantees that objects which are equal will have the same hash code, which is all that's required for *correctness*. Beyond correctness, ensuring that non-equal objects have different hash codes is a matter of making it *efficient* to use the type in a hash-based lookup.

Comment: Thanks Jon and always great to learn from you. I posted some other code which is using the Line object, you can find it leverages hash map to check if line are identical, I think when this line of code is called, "line_count.containsKey(line)", the hash value of the line object is used as key? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @LinMa: No, the hash code is used to quickly find keys that *might* be equal - but it will still call `equals` to validate that. You can check this easily - create a map with two keys that are non-equal but have the same hash code. You'll still be able to use those two keys independently.

Comment: Thanks Jon, then what is the value of hash value? We can just use equal directly? Suppose the scenario is to calculate histogram, we need to calculate # of duplicate records on each line (combination of slope/intercept).

Comment: @LinMa: I suggest you read up on hash tables, basically. By finding the hash code as an integer, you can really, really quickly find keys that *might* be equal... instead of having to call `equals` on every key.

Comment: Thanks Jon, do you have any suggested document/code to read for a newbie?

Comment: @LinMa: I'd probably start on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks Jon, do you know for Python dictionary, it is implemented the same way internally?

Comment: @LinMa: No, and this is now a very long way from your original question.